# How to optimizing Do and Manipulate for image processing purposes (Gravitational Lensing)?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, image-processing, parallelization

I am trying to replicate [LensToy](http://slowe.github.io/LensToy/) using Mathematica, which is a web-based gravitational lensing simulator. I am having issues with `Manipulate`/`Dynamics`, especially with its performance. I am guessing it is because I am calling a function with a `Do` loop, called `getSkyData`, within a `Manipulate`. If only called once, `getSkyData` will take 0.45 seconds to run. `ParallelDo` takes 5 seconds!?! Why such a simple operation (i.e. $440 \times 440 \times 3$ variable assignments) takes such a long time? Is it because Mathematica is not meant for doing big loops and I should use other techniques? Then, how can I optimize `getSkyData`? How can I properly call `getSkyData` within a `Manipulate`/`DynamicModule`?

[image]

**Details (if interested!)**

The following is the piece of code relevant to this question. At the end, you can find the entire code. If you change `False` to `True`, the code will run the `Manipulate` and your Mathematica notebook might freeze.

If the code is too complicated, let me know and I will remove all the physics and make up a simpler problem.

```
fullMap = 
  Table[{{i, j}, lensMap[{i, j}, {0, 0}]}, {i, imax}, {j, jmax}];

getSkyData[srcCoord_] := Block[{skyData = foregroundData},
  Do[
   {{i, j}, {l, m}} = elem;
   {l, m} = {l, m} - srcCoord;
   If[0 < l < lmax && 0 < m < mmax, 
    skyData[[i, j]] += 2 sourceData[[l, m]]],
   {elem, Flatten[fullMap, 1]}];
  skyData]



If[False,

 Manipulate[Graphics[Raster[getSkyData[coord]]] // Dynamic,
  {{coord, lensCoord, "Source Coord"}, {1, 1}, {imax, jmax}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> Style["+", FontSize -> 50, White]}],

 Graphics[Raster[getSkyData[lensCoord]]] // AbsoluteTiming

 ]
```

`lensMap` finds the associated background pixel.

`getSkyData` takes the coordinate of the corner of the background source/galaxy image. Then it goes through all the sky pixels (i.e. the larger image that you will see, i.e. the end result). If the pixel in hand maps to a background pixel (i.e. one of the $16 \times 16 \times 3$ of the background image), it will add it to the foreground pixel in question. This if statement is for optimization purposes.

**The entire code**

```
img0 = Import["http://slowe.github.io/LensToy/SW_field_440x440.png"];

foreground = ImageTrim[img0, {{0 + 1, 0 + 1}, {440 - 1, 440 - 1}}] ;

sourceCoord = {28, 231};
sourceBoxSize = 7;

source = ImageTrim[
   img0, {sourceCoord - sourceBoxSize {1, 1}, 
    sourceCoord + sourceBoxSize {1, 1}}]; 

foregroundData = ImageData[foreground];

Graphics[Raster[%]];

sourceData = ImageData[source];
Graphics[Raster[%]];


{imax, jmax} = foreground // ImageDimensions;
{lmax, mmax} = source // ImageDimensions;

lensCoord = {259, 281};

arcsec = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "ArcSeconds"], "Radians"][[1]] // N;
pixel = 1;
resolution = 0.1 arcsec/pixel;

pix2Sky[{i_, j_}] := {(i - 1), (j - 1)} resolution
src2Pix[rSrc_] := Floor[rSrc/resolution] + {1, 1}
lensCenterSky = pix2Sky[lensCoord];
sky2Lens[rSky_] := 
 Block[{r = rSky - lensCenterSky}, {Norm[r], 
   If[r != {0, 0}, ArcTan[##] & @@ r, {0., 0.}]}]
lens2Sky[rLns_] := {rLns[[1]] Cos[rLns[[2]]], 
   rLns[[1]] Sin[rLns[[2]]]} + lensCenterSky

thetaE = 3 arcsec;
lensEquation[rLns_, thetaE_] := 
 Block[{theta = rLns[[1]], 
   phi = rLns[[2]]}, {If[theta != 0, theta - thetaE^2/theta, 0], phi}]

lensMap[{i_, j_}, src0SkyPix_] := Block[{},
  rSky = pix2Sky[{i, j}];
  rLns = sky2Lens[rSky];
  rSrc = (lensEquation[rLns, thetaE] // lens2Sky) - 
    pix2Sky[src0SkyPix];
  src2Pix[rSrc]
  ]

(* vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv *)

fullMap = 
  Table[{{i, j}, lensMap[{i, j}, {0, 0}]}, {i, imax}, {j, jmax}];

getSkyData[srcCoord_] := Block[{skyData = foregroundData},
  Do[
   {{i, j}, {l, m}} = elem;
   {l, m} = {l, m} - srcCoord;
   If[0 < l < lmax && 0 < m < mmax, 
    skyData[[i, j]] += 2 sourceData[[l, m]]],
   {elem, Flatten[fullMap, 1]}];
  skyData]



If[False,

 Manipulate[Graphics[Raster[getSkyData[coord]]] // Dynamic,
  {{coord, lensCoord, "Source Coord"}, {1, 1}, {imax, jmax}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> Style["+", FontSize -> 50, White]}],

 Graphics[Raster[getSkyData[lensCoord]]] // AbsoluteTiming

 ]
```

Comment: I previously asked a similar question (the link below), but I have drastically modified my code and resolved some of the stated issues. The question has been deleted now.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149447/gravitational-lensing-simulation-coordinate-and-rendering-issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [a lot of good answers on performance-tuning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning?sort=votes), so I'm not going to repeat them. Read at least the first 3-5 of them! They've got many upvotes for a reason.

But for your code (as far as I understand it), I would:

- replace "pattern matching" functions with pure functions (pattern matching enables elegant code, but it's more expensive than a function call)
- use `With[` to tell Mathematica when it can treat a value as a constant
- Use [`ImageTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTransformation.html) instead of your own loop
- Don't use `Raster` unless you really want a grid of rectangles. Use `Image` if you want an image

I didn't understand all of your code, so I'll just give a simple example, that you can probably adapt to what you want to do. This takes about 150ms on my PC:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfRGK.jpg"];

With[{thetaE = 0.1},
 ImageTransformation[ImageCrop[img],
  Function[pt,
   With[{theta = Norm[pt]},
    pt*(theta - thetaE/theta)/theta]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]